# Windows of difference between 2 time series

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, time-series, data-science

I am trying to find 3 areas of difference between 2 time series. I am able to see the difference between the 2 but i want to eventually automatically detect the biggest difference and the smaller between the 2 curves. Using the following code i can view the difference between the 2 curves but i want to be able to find the 3 areas (chronologically) by defining a number of points or time period like in the image. So, for example find 3 windows of a week each where the difference is small then big and then small again. Any idea if there is a build in function for this?
Thank you

```
ax.fill_between(
    x=feature.reset_index().index, 
    y1=feature.1, 
    y2=feature.2, 
    alpha=0.3
)
```

[The 2 time series and 3 wanted areas that i would like to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcr6A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As a concept: 
Define a large time window as t_0 to T, find the initial minimum in the difference of the two series (i.e. find the minimum of the spread) and record the location of this time. If you have an aligned data.frame of the time series this should be rudimentary in finding the minimum of the difference and looking up the loc of that item to identify the time within the window.

Then restrict your search to t_min_1 to T, and search for the maximum, again obtaining the loc for this maximum value in the spread. Lastly, search over t_max to T, for a local minimum within the spread and find the loc for that value.

This will return for you in your given window the times of your first minimum (t_min_1), second maximum (t_max) and third minimum (t_min_2) following within each event.